# JS: timeupdate unhide multiple divs at different times on same video, getElementbyId issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, video

So basically here's what I'm trying to do: when the video plays and hits a timestamp a div pops up on the video with a clickable button.

This works when its run once but if it is called again with a seperate div at another time it will not work.

In the example, the first button displays from 5-10 seconds, but the second div that is meant to display at 11-15 seconds does not work.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var growVideo=document.getElementById("videogrow");
var growLearnButton = document.getElementById("growLearn");
var growLearnCloseButton = document.getElementById("growLearnClose");
var growDoButton = document.getElementById("growDo");
var growDoCloseButton = document.getElementById("growDoClose");


//GrowLearnMoreGuide

 // Event listener for the guide buttons
   growLearnButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (growVideo.paused == true) {
  // Play the video
  growVideo.play();

  // Update the button text to 'Pause'
  growLearnButton.innerHTML = "Grow: Learn More";
} else {
  // Pause the video
  growVideo.pause();

  // Update the button text to 'Play'
  growLearnButton.innerHTML = "Grow: Learn More";
}
});

// Event listener for the close buttons
growLearnCloseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (growVideo.paused == true) {
  // Play the video
  growVideo.play();

  // Update the button text to 'Pause'
  growLearnCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Grow";
} else {
  // Pause the video
  growVideo.pause();

  // Update the button text to 'Play'
  growLearnCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Grow";
}
});



    var GrowDoMore = document.getElementById("GrowDoMore");
    var GrowDoMorestart = GrowDoMore.getAttribute('data-starttime');
    var GrowDoMoreend = GrowDoMore.getAttribute('data-endtime');


    videogrow.ontimeupdate = function(e)

      {
        var hasHidden = GrowDoMore.hasAttribute("hidden");
        if (growVideo.currentTime > GrowDoMorestart && growVideo.currentTime < GrowDoMoreend)
          {
            if (hasHidden) {
              GrowDoMore.removeAttribute("hidden");
            }
          }
          else
            {
              if (!hasHidden) {
                GrowDoMore.setAttribute("hidden", "");
              }
            }
          }

var GrowLearnMore = document.getElementById("GrowLearnMore");
    var GrowLearnMorestart = GrowLearnMore.getAttribute('data-starttime');
    var GrowLearnMoreend = GrowLearnMore.getAttribute('data-endtime');

 videogrow.ontimeupdate = function(e)

{
var hasHidden = GrowLearnMore.hasAttribute("hidden");
  if (growVideo.currentTime > GrowLearnMorestart && growVideo.currentTime < GrowLearnMoreend)
{
  if (hasHidden) {
GrowLearnMore.removeAttribute("hidden");
  }
}
else
{
   if (!hasHidden) {
   GrowLearnMore.setAttribute("hidden", "");
  }
 }
}

    //GrowDoMoreGuide



    // Event listener for the guide buttons
      growDoButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (growVideo.paused == true) {
          // Play the video
          growVideo.play();

          // Update the button text to 'Pause'
          growDoButton.innerHTML = "Grow: Do More";
        } else {
          // Pause the video
          growVideo.pause();

          // Update the button text to 'Play'
          growDoButton.innerHTML = "Grow: Do More";
        }
      });

      // Event listener for the close buttons
      growDoCloseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (growVideo.paused == true) {
          // Play the video
          growVideo.play();

          // Update the button text to 'Pause'
          growDoCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Part 1: Grow";
        } else {
          // Pause the video
          growVideo.pause();

          // Update the button text to 'Play'
          growDoCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Part 1: Grow";
        }
      });
```

HTML:

```
<video id="videogrow" controls>
                <!-- Video files -->
                <source src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.webm" type="video/webm">

                <!-- Text track file -->
                <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt" default>

                <!-- Fallback for browsers that don't support the <video> element -->
                <a href="https://cdn.selz.com/plyr/1.5/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.mp4" download>Download</a>
            </video>

            <!-- LEARN MORE-->

              <div id="GrowLearnMore" hidden data-starttime="5" data-endtime="10">
                <button type="button" class="GrowLearnGuide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GrowLearnModal" id="growLearn">Grow: Learn More</button>
              </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="GrowLearnModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Grow: Learn More">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <!-- <div class="modal-content">-->
                  <a href="http://www.nascireland.org/" target="blank"><img src="http://fareireland.ie/imgs/tobleroneframe.jpg" class="center" /></a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                  <div class="closeButton1"><button type="button" class="GrowLearnGuide btn growLearn" data-dismiss="modal" id="growLearnClose">Back to Documentary X</button></div>
                </div><!--</modal>-->
              </div><!--</modal>-->
            <!-- END LEARN MORE-->

            <!-- DO MORE-->
             <div id="GrowDoMore" hidden data-starttime="11" data-endtime="15">
                <button type="button" class="GrowDoGuide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GrowDoModal" id="growDo">Grow: Do More</button>
             </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="GrowDoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Grow: Do More">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <!-- <div class="modal-content">-->
                    <a href="http://www.nascireland.org/" target="blank"><img src="imgs/doMore.png" width ="50%" class="center" /></a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <div class="closeButton2"><button type="button" id="growDoClose" class="GrowDoGuide btn growDo" data-dismiss="modal" >Back to Documentary X</button></div>
                  </div><!--</modal>-->
                </div><!--</modal>-->
                <!-- END DO MORE-->
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m615t5LL/6/

I think this might be something to do with the fact it is calling videogrow which is an ID twice, but I dont know how to fix it.

I've tried changing it to a class in the JS, and calling the video twice in the html eg.

```
<div class="videogrow videogrow2">
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you really intent to have two variables `growVideo` and `videogrow`? As far as I can tell, it should be one or the other all through.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple errors.

1. `growVideo` suddenly becomes `videogrow` part way through the code.
2. the syntax `element.onxxx = handler;` allows you to attach *one* handler. A second attachment using the same syntax will wipe the first. Contrast that with `element.addEventListener("eventName", handler)` or jQuery's `$(selector).on('eventName', handler)`, which allow multiple handlers to be attached to the same element.

In practice, the attachment thing is not actually a big issue here because the simple fix is to do both show/hide actions in the *same* event handler.

Exploiting jQuery to keep the code concise, I would write something like this :

```
var growVideo = $("#videogrow").get(0); // element
var $growDoMore = $("#GrowDoMore"); // jQuery object
var $growLearnMore = $("#GrowLearnMore"); // jQuery object

//GrowLearnMoreGuide
// Event listener for the guide buttons
$("#growLearn").on('click', function() {
    if (growVideo.paused == true) {
        growVideo.play(); // Play the video
        $(this).text("Grow: Learn More"); // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    } else {
        growVideo.pause(); // Pause the video
        $(this).text("Grow: Learn More"); // Update the button text to 'Play'
    }
});

// Event listener for the close buttons
$("#growLearnClose").on('click', function() {
    if (growVideo.paused == true) {
        growVideo.play(); // Play the video
        $(this).text("X Back to Grow"); // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    } else {
        growVideo.pause(); // Pause the video
        $(this).text("X Back to Grow"); // Update the button text to 'Play'
    }
});

$(growVideo).on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    // show/hide growDoMore
    if (this.currentTime > $growDoMore.data('starttime') && this.currentTime < $growDoMore.data('endtime')) {
        $growDoMore.show();
    } else {
        $growDoMore.hide();
    }
    // show/hide growLearnMore
    if (this.currentTime > $growLearnMore.data('starttime') && this.currentTime < $growLearnMore.data('endtime')) {
        $growLearnMore.show();
    } else {
        $growLearnMore.hide();
    }
});

// GrowDoMoreGuide
// Event listener for the guide buttons
$("#growDo").on('click', function() {
    if (growVideo.paused) {
        growVideo.play(); // Play the video
        $(this).text("Grow: Do More"); // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    } else {
        growVideo.pause(); // Pause the video
        $(this).text("Grow: Do More"); // Update the button text to 'Play'
    }
});

// Event listener for the close buttons
$("#growDoClose").on('click', function() {
    if (growVideo.paused) {
        growVideo.play(); // Play the video
        growDoCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Part 1: Grow"; // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    } else {
        growVideo.pause(); // Pause the video
        growDoCloseButton.innerHTML = "X Back to Part 1: Grow"; // Update the button text to 'Play'
    }
});
```